# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I used arrays for my table :

```
var html = [];
$.each(data,function(index,item){
   no++;
   var arr = [
    '<tr>',
       '<td>'+ no +'</td>',
       '<td>'+ item.name +'</td>',
       '<td>'+ item.address +'</td>',
       '<td>',
         '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="pickData('+ item.id +','+ item.name +','+ item.address +')"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>',
    '</td>',
    '</tr>'
    ].join('\n');
    html.push(arr);
});
$('#table').html(html);
```

and this is the function :

```
function pickData(id, name, address) {
    $("#id").val(id);
    $(".name").val(name);
    $(".address").val(address);
}
```

The error is :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Where is the problem?

Comment: does it say what line it is?

Comment: No, I try with function pickData(id) and it's work. But when I used 3 variables, that's getting error

Comment: Inspect your resulting code. You will find something like `onclick="pickData(123,foo,bar)"` ie you are missing the quotes for around your string parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you write code,
Please check your variable (especially address and name) value from console.log,
Make sure it doesn't contains space on it.

Ie. "Malibu" Vs "Malibu street",

If it does contains space, you need to quotes those variable value.
Because when you're not place quotes, your function would be invoked like this:
pickData("yourId", "yourName", Malibu street)

Meanwhile the function itself expect like this:
pickData("yourId", "yourName", "Malibu street")